# How can I create a method of finding the total number of possible combinations using a dynamic format

Tags: javascript, php, math, combinations, permutation

I have a randomly generated custom number plate format which is as follows:

> ISSIIIISS - Where 'I' is an Integer of 0-9 and 'S' is a string of A-Z
>
> An example plate would be: 4DE2947BN

I am trying to find a way in which to calculate the total number of all possible combinations of this number plate format.

How can I do this and how could I use PHP or JavaScript to solve this problem?

I have some grasp of how you can calculate combinations but I am struggling on how this can be implemented into code, especially with the alphanumeric format that I am trying to calculate.

Comment: I understand the maths principle of calculating combinations but I don't really understand how this can be implemented in code. That's the part I'm struggling with, especially with the alphanumeric format that I have.

Sorry if this is the wrong place though

Comment: Substitute each integer with 10 & letter with 26, & multiply all. Like 10*26*26*10*10*10*10*26*26*

Comment: @Charlie If you can write out the math for calculating this, it is still unclear what is stopping you from putting said math formula into your code.  Are you wanting something _dynamic_ where you can change the format and get a different result?

Comment: @PatrickQ Yeah, I was looking for a way which you could replace it with other formats too. I could've explained it a bit better but I was just a bit confused as looking at answers before posting were a bit convoluted. Cid and Cat have given me the clarity I was looking for. Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I` being a number, there is 10 possibilities.

`S` being a character, there is 26 possibilities.

The total number of combinations is `10 power (TheNumberOfI) * 26 power (TheNumberOfS)`

This can be dynamically solved using a simple function that counts the number of `S` and the number of `I` and uses the results in the previous equation

```js
function getNumberOfCombinations(input)
{
    const countI = (input.match(/I/g) || []).length;
    const countS = (input.match(/S/g) || []).length;
    const result =  Math.pow(10, countI) * Math.pow(26, countS);
    return (result);
}

console.log(getNumberOfCombinations("ISSIIIISS"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I was over complicating it much more than needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should become clear if you take it a piece at a time.
For the first "I", there are 10 possibilities, and for the first "S", there are 26,
so for those two characters together, the total number of possibilities is `10 x 26 = 260`.

Then for the next "S", you have 26 possibilities, so the first three characters together have `10 x 26 x 26 = 6760` possibilities.

The pattern continues until you get `26^4 * 10^5 = 45,697,600,000`, which in JS is
`26**4 * 10**4` 
or

```js
let x = Math.pow(26,4) * Math.pow(10,5);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thank you :) I think I was over complicating it much more than needed when looking at answers before posting. Appreciate the help!